# Relative layout placing to other relative layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing a chat app.I want to place edittext to bottom then messages above it.But I have a problem:

[image]

I don't want to place messages to top of edittext and button.How can I prevent this ? This is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ECECFB"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/message_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

 <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >


           <EditText
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 

               <Button
        android:id="@+id/get_from_user"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="Gönder" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And I have one more question.How can I do message list system like other chat apps ? I mean when I send a message this message place to bottom of the list not to top.Now in my xml it's placing to top.Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your `ListView` above the `EditText` layout.
Your layout will be as below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ECECFB">

 <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/bottom_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >


        <EditText
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 

        <Button
        android:id="@+id/get_from_user"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="Gönder" />
    </RelativeLayout>

     <ListView
        android:id="@+id/message_list"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And for your second problem, set

```
android:stackFromBottom="true"
android:transcriptMode="normal"
```

to the `ListView`

Answer (score 1):

First Problem:
You need to set on RelativeLayout

```
android:bellow="@+id/message_list"
```

2º Problem:
You need to set on ListView:

```
android:stackFromBottom="true"
android:transcriptMode="normal"
```

Final Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ECECFB"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/message_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:transcriptMode="normal"/>

 <RelativeLayout
        android:bellow="@+id/message_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >


           <EditText
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 

               <Button
        android:id="@+id/get_from_user"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="Gönder" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I tried your xml but my edittext and button has gone away.It's not showing.

Comment: Test now mate! You need to remove             android:layout_weight="1"

Answer (score 1):

For example, add

```
android:layout_below="@id/message_list"
```

to your inner `RelativeLayout`to constrain the `ListView` and bottom `RelativeLayout` not to lay out on top of each other.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Add this to your Relative layout : android:layout_below="@+id/message_list"

and change your listview to wrap_content

Answer (score 1):

Basically do this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ECECFB"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/comment_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/message"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/get_from_user"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:text="Gönder" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/message_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/comment_layout"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/message_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

To this:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/message_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

This should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:layout_above="@+id/id_of_relative_layout"`. 
Add an ID to the **RelativeLayout** which contains the **EditText**.